# The value of req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, ajax

I made the following post request but what gets printed in the console is: result---------------undefined.

How can I get the input name printed in the console instead of undefined?

index.html

```
<form>
    <label>Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="zyd317"></label>
<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("post", "http://localhost:8888", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    data = JSON.stringify({"key": name});
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
    function onRequest(req,res) {
        console.log("result-----------"+req.body);
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:63342"});
        res.end();
    }
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888, function () {
    console.log("listening................");
});
```

server.js

Comment: You are never sending the `data`

Answer (score 2):

### Your problem:

**Server-side:** The `req.body` property is only defined when you are using the [Express framework](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body). In native Node.js, `req.body` is not a property of the `req` parameter ([docs here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage)). You have to receive the data and parse it manually.

**Client-side:** Your HTML form handling is not set up properly. From the way you set up your HTML file, the script inside the `<script>` tag will execute as soon as everything else before it loads, even if the `name` field is empty.

### Solution:

**Server-side**

```js
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(req, res) {
  // Check the request method
  if(req.method == "POST") {
    var data = [];

    req.on("data", function(chunk) {
      data.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on("end", function() {
      data = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

      try {
        // Try to parse the data
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        // Log the data
        console.log(data);
        // Give a response
        res.writeHead(200,{
          "Content-Type":"text/plain",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:63342"
        });
        res.end("Data parsed");
      } catch (err) {
        // Bad JSON!
        console.error(err);
        // Give a response
        res.writeHead(400,{
          "Content-Type":"text/plain",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:63342"
        });
        res.end("Bad request");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200,{
      "Content-Type":"text/plain",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:63342"
    });
    res.end("Hello world!");
  }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888, function () {
    console.log("listening................");
});
```

This is your original server, modified a bit. Here, we check if the request method is post. If it isn't, just send a generic "Hello world!" response. If it is, however, receive the request body, and then parse it with `JSON.parse()`. The `req` parameter implements the `ReadableStream` interface, as stated [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body).

**Client-side**

```html
<form id="formID">
    <label>Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="zyd317"></label>
<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
  function sendFormData(e) {
    // Do this to prevent the default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    // Initialize the XHR request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8888", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var data = JSON.stringify({"key": name});
    xhr.send(data);
  }

  var form = document.getElementById("formID");
  // Register the event handler
  form.addEventListener('submit', sendFormData);
</script>
```

Here on your client side, I only changed a few things: one, put the data sending in a function, and two, added an event handler so that your script won't send the data right away. Oh, and also, I made the function actually send data using `xhr.send(data);`

Hope this helps:)

Comment: You are my hero, thanks! I wouldn't think about parse it manually in chunks in a million years!

Comment: what does `data = Buffer.concat(body).toString();` do?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code on the server to the following:

```
var http = require("http");
function onRequest(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"});
    let body = [];
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(body);
    });
    res.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888, function () {
    console.log("listening................");
});
```

*Note:* `Content-Type` on the client side and on the server side were not the same previously, so I set it on the server to match the client's request.

[here's the official node js guide for reference](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you are never passing the data generated at the client side with the request,

So if you change this line

`xhr.send();`

to

`xhr.send(data)`;

It will work